# I need a "speak with strangers" app

Tags: android

I need an android app to make new friends from all over the world.

1. I wouldn't like to pick people up by their profile. Waiting for them to agree or approve my friendship is boring. I need to connect automatically to random people who are online.
2. Calls are better than chat.
3. I need a clean app that doesn't need any other software to work such as Google play services.